# Is refreshing data every time duration to check for new orders in admin page bad?

Tags: reactjs, database, push-notification, fetch, admin

I built an admin page in React.js to check for new orders placed, but I used a `useEffect` with `setInterval` for a specific duration (30 seconds for example) to keep on fetching new orders from the backend and mysql server.
Is this a bad pattern or not? Is the a better way , maybe to notify the admin that there are new orders then he will refresh manually?
Thanks!

Comment: https://socket.io